# What's faster, referencing a property in an outer table or comparing against a parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I realize this example is entirely contrived, but I'm looking for a general rule of thumb here; is there any difference from a performance standpoint between these two queries?

**Example 1: Reference outer table:**

```
select o.id, o.name,
(select count(*) from inner_table i1 where i1.outerid = o.id),
(select sum(i2.amount) from other_inner_table i2 where i2.outerid = o.id)
from outer_table o
where o.id = @outerid
```

**Example 2: Compare directly against parameter:**

```
select o.id, o.name,
(select count(*) from inner_table i1 where i1.outerid = @outerid),
(select sum(i2.amount) from other_inner_table i2 where i2.outerid = @outerid)
from outer_table o
where o.id = @outerid
```

I primarily use Sql Server 2008 R2, but I'd be interested in answers specific to any RDMS.

**Update:**

I realize this is hightly contextual; I guess I was just curious if this was only a stylistic choice or if there were circumstances where this would actual make a difference. I realize I could just "test it and see" for specific cases - but that's not really the answer I'm after.

Comment: In a quick experiment with empty tables (under 2008, not R2), in both cases, the predicate `outerid = @outerid` was used against the inner tables (i.e. the optimizer transformed example 1 into something resembling example 2 anyway). But as others say, you'd need to try it on your system, with your data, your indexes, etc.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - If you'll reword your comment as an answer (with a little bit of contextual data, etc), I will accept it as the answer as it was the closest to what I was looking for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created some completely empty tables, with only the required columns to allow your queries to run:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[inner_table](
    [outerid] [int] NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[other_inner_table](
    [outerid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [amount] [int] NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[outer_table](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](30) NOT NULL
)
```

I then turned on Execution plans, and executed both queries. In both cases, this showed that all 3 tables were being scanned (as expected, with no/low rows). In particular, the scan against `inner_table` has a predicate of:

```
[DBName].[dbo].[inner_table].[outerid] as [i1].[outerid]=[@outerid]
```

and the scan against `other_inner_table` has a predicate of:

```
[DBName].[dbo].[other_inner_table].[outerid] as [i2].[outerid]=[@outerid]
```

That is, in the first example, the optimizer has identified that the outer where clauses condition of `where o.id = @outerid` implies that, within the subqueries, `o.id` is always equal to `@outerid`, and has performed that substitution.

In general, unless there is a performance issue, you shouldn't try to "help" SQL by transforming the queries by hand. There are something like 300 different optimizations that the optimizer has available to it - you might not pick the best one(s).

Answer (score 1):

One of the pluses and minuses of SQL is that it's high level so you can only be sure by getting the explain plan and testing a specific case to be sure of the outcome. It's no uncommon to answer most database question with...it depends.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to answer this; what do yor indexes look like? constraints? statistics?  What's the distribution of data on i2.outerid?  How much RAM do you have on your server?

Sometime performance tuning is a science; usually it's voodoo. :)